# wixtoolset Nuget 4.3 fail on restore wixproj

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, wix, nuget

I update my nuget to 4.3, since then, there are always an error when my build system try to restore nuget packages

I’m using VS2017, version 15.3.5, and wixtoolset installed

```
  "C:\NuGet\NuGet.exe" restore "C:\...\....sln" -ConfigFile "C:\....\NuGet.config" -NoCache -NonInteractive -Verbosity detailed
  NuGet Version: 4.3.0.4406
  MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.3.409.57025' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.

C:\... \Setup\Setup.wixproj : error MSB4057: The target "_IsProjectRestoreSupported" does not exist in the project.
```

Comment: Did this issue only occurs with tfs build or also on the local through VS/Msbuild?

Comment: it occurs localy if I run the command on command line and even if I run on VS. I'm using XAML builds

Comment: If so, seems not related to TFS side, suggest you to  remove TFS tag and add Nuget tag which could obtain more accurate attention.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice

Comment: Is the NuGet package manager installed in VS? (check in vs installer > modify > individual components). If not, can you share your wixproj files and packages.config for that project?

Comment: Another question: the error should happen but NuGet should ignore it and restore successfully, is the build task maybe configured to fail on error output? if so, try deactivating this behaviour to ignore the error output and only determine success based on the return code

Comment: Yes, the QA not allows this fails, and this is the reason why it fails. However, it should do the restore, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> wixtoolset Nuget 4.3 fail on restore wixproj

I got the same error as you when I use `NuGet.exe` v4.3.0 restore package for WiX Toolset project. Then I found that there is a `_IsProjectRestoreSupported` target was added in `NuGet.exe` v4.3.0 which will be called for each project to verify that the restore targets exist. This change is used to fix the NuGet issue 5530. For more detail information, you can check below link:

https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/pull/1550

**As a workaround**, you can use the [NuGet.exe v4.1.0](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v4.1.0/nuget.exe) instead of `NuGet.exe` v4.3.0 in the folder `C:\NuGet`, or restore NuGet package by Visual Studio. Above change applies only to the command line, VS does not have these issues since the project systems are available to read the projects.

Besides, for the issue on the version v4.3.0, I have submit a new issue on GitHub:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5940

Hope this helps.